# UPDATE a field with SQL where another field is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to auto update with PHP/SQL the last_modified datetime of an entry. The city vars I am binding could sometimes filled with a city and sometimes stay empty or mixed filled and empty.

How can I just apply a clause within the WHERE clause if city is NOT empty? The problem is, I have some entries with empty cities in the database, so if a binded var is empty it will also be updated.

I tried it with  "city <> ''" but it isn't working properly and shows me more results that expected.

```
UPDATE result_page
SET last_modified = ?
WHERE city = ? OR city = ? OR city = ? OR city = ? AND city <> ''
```

Comment: I'd consider having a constraint that rejects zero length city names.

Comment: *or mixed filled and empty.* ??? How single value can be both filled and empty at the same time? Show some data example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE result_page 
  SET last_modified = ? 
     WHERE city <> '' AND (city = ? OR city = ? OR city = ? OR city = ?)
```

Comment: If `city <> ''` is FALSE and none parameter is empty string then the whole WHERE is FALSE. If any `city = ?` with non-empty parameter is TRUE then `city <> ''` is TRUE. Hence if none parameter is empty string then the condition `city <> ''` is excess and can be removed.